# Quais são as formas mais comuns de fazer inserção de dados remotamente?

Tags: .net

Tenho várias aplicações onde realizo constantes inserções de dados no banco de dados local, porém, o número de aplicações simultâneas ficou muito grande e os dados estão atrasados. Agora, necessito dividir essas aplicações em servidores distintos para conseguir manter os dados atualizados em tempo real.

Quais são as formas mais comuns de inserir dados remotamente e concorrentemente com alta performance (Client XML, JSON, API, WebService, etc.)?

Comment: [Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx)

É a arquitetura orientada a serviços da Microsoft. [Você pode começar por este tutorial, se quiser aprender desde já](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835(v=vs.110).aspx).

WCF pode trabalhar, em teoria, com qualquer modelo de dados, como XML (padrão), [JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec), [OData](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/514598/Understanding-OData-v-and-WCF-Data-Services-x), ou ainda um formato não usual, como [YAML](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73c1b1c2-8085-46d0-9635-efcef68bcc70/i-have-a-wcf-restful-service-and-i-want-it-to-return-data-in-format-of-yaml?forum=wcf).

## [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Esta arquitetura é mais simples que o WCF em termos de configurações e tende a ser mais granularizada. Enquanto que o WCF trabalha melhor em requisições atômicas (uma chamada para realizar toda a tarefa), o Web API trabalha melhor devidindo a tarefa em várias requisições (mais orientada a recursos).

O formato padrão de transferência de dados é o JSON, mas o Web API também trabalha com [XML](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) e [YAML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amido.Net.Http.Formatting.YamlMediaTypeFormatter/).

## Fora do escopo da pergunta, mas também interessante: [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)

Este é mais por curiosidade porque foge ao escopo .NET, mas pode ser interessante pra você saber. O SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) integra bancos de dados em SQL Server de forma transparente. Pode ser uma opção se o desejo é boa sincronicidade e performance.

Comment: Qual você usaria? (Considerando o cenário que apresentei). Sobre o SSIS, utilizo o SQL Server, é uma alternativa viável.

Comment: Web API, por ser mais eclética. WCF é uma alternativa mais antiga e mais engessada, portanto.